# How to make Rails 3 reload STI classes in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

After switching to Rails 3, I noticed that I have to reboot my server to make STI model classes reload with each request. For example, suppose I have this:

```
# app/models/vehicle.rb
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/car.rb
class Car < Vehicle
end
```

If I make a change to `Vehicle`, the change is loaded on the next request. But if I make a change to `Car`, I have to reboot my server for it to load.

Any ideas on fixing this?

I'm running WEBrick, but I'm not committed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that we needed both zetetic's solution and some additional code to make this work (at least in Rails 3.0.9). For the above problem, the solution would look something like:

In config/environments/development.rb:

```
  config.after_initialize do
    ["vehicle"].each do|dep|
      require_dependency( (Rails.root + "app/models/#{dep}").to_s )
    end
  end
```

In app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  if Rails.env == 'development'
    require_dependency( (Rails.root + "app/models/vehicle").to_s )
  end
...
```

The code in development.rb handles the initial loading of the class, and the code in ApplicationController handles subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be solved by adding `require_dependency 'vehicle'` in the controller.

Comment: I believe require_dependency is part of a private API. Also, it seems to me that this shouldn't be necessary, as STI and autoloading are theoretically supported out of the box. I'm hoping there's some solution that involves a global config or fixing my development server.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be necessary, but it is. STI has a few quirks that need workarounds -- this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using rails 3.0.3 and passenger 3, I don't see this at all. If updating your app to 3.0.3 doesn't fix it, I'd move off of WEBrick.

I personally recommend using something other than WEBrick anyway. Passenger has been my server of choice for development + production for quite a while now.

Comment: definitely not server related... unicorn and thin here... rails 3.0.9 similar issues...