# How to reload files in app/models/subdirectory in dev environment for STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, development-environment, single-table-inheritance

I implemented STI in one of my models, using some tips from [Alex Reisner's blog post](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html). I already had all my subclasses use the superclass's controller, with serialize/store to hold the extra attributes. I added the `model_name` and `self.select_options` methods to the superclass, and the preload initializer from Alex's blog. I also changed my `collection_select` in the _form view helper and attribute validation to use the `self.select_options` method. All my subclasses are in individual files in a app/models/subfolder, though they're not namespaced like SubFolder::Subclass.

Then I start running into problems. Upon changing any code, `self.select_options` stops returning all of the subclasses. It only returns a small subset or none. Thus due to the validation and _form tie-in, I can't edit/update my models after a code change. From what I could tell, when I change any code, Rails reloads the environment, but not the models in the subfolder.

I tried adding the routes to config.autoload_paths [like many suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3/9819938#9819938), but ultimately that didn't work.

So ultimately, I want:

- Something to fix the autoloading, so I won't have to restart the server after every change
- Base it off the subdirectory containing all the children, to avoid manually maintaining an array
- Rails 3.2.11, ruby 1.9.3p125, ubuntu 12.04.01, rvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up combining the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680809/1777670) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309126/1777670) and knowledge gleaned from the [wondible](http://wondible.com) blog posts at the bottom. The `config.autoload_paths` never seemed to help anything, but I kept them in there. The key part is the initializer that requires all the files in the subdirectory on startup and then at each reload. I tried `load` over `require_dependency`, which didn't work. It's definitely been nice not having to reload all the time.

In application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/configuration)
```

In development.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/configuration/**"]
```

In preload_sti_models.rb

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/app/models/subfolder").each do |c|
    require_dependency File.join("app","models", "subfolder", "#{c}") if c =~ /.rb$/
  end
  ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
    Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/app/models/subfolder").each do |c|
      require_dependency File.join("app","models", "subfolder", "#{c}") if c =~ /.rb$/
    end
  end
end
```

Some blog posts with useful information

1. http://wondible.com/2012/01/13/rails-3-2-autoloading-in-theory/
2. http://wondible.com/2011/12/30/rails-autoloading-cleaning-up-the-mess/
3. http://wondible.com/2011/12/23/give-rails-autoloading-a-boot-to-the-head/
4. http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/

Edit: [it's a known thing](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8699).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to undefinedvariable's above, but a bit more DRY.

```
# organize your sti classes in directories named after the parent
sti_directory_paths = [
  Rails.root.join("app","models","subfolder_one"),
  Rails.root.join("app","models","subfolder_two"),
]

def require_sti_model(path, filename)
  require_dependency (path + filename).to_s
end

# if you use something like guard, just exclude from production
unless Rails.env.production?
  sti_directory_paths.each do |sti_directory_path|
    Dir[sti_directory_path + "*.rb"].each do |filename|
      require_sti_model(sti_directory_path, filename)
      ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
        require_sti_model(sti_directory_path, filename)
      end
    end
  end
end
```